# How to use "*.objects.values()" in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a table name "Like" and column named "value". It contains two values, either "Like" or "Unlike". How do i get the column value with only "Like" using Like.objects.values(). I have tried,

```
query = Like.objects.values({'value': 'Like'}).order_by().annotate(Count('value'))
```

It's throwing,

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The objective is to get the no of likes in descending order. If i get it using object.values(), I can do something like below to sort,

```
sorted_dec = sorted(query, key=lambda x:x['value'], reverse=True)[0:5]
```

Or is there any better logic to approach this?

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = RichTextField(blank=False, null=True, validators=[MinLengthValidator(200)])
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True, related_name = 'liked')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'author')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def num_likes(self):
        return self.liked.all().count()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

LIKE_CHOICES = (

('Like', 'Like'),
('Unlike', 'Unlike'),

)

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices= LIKE_CHOICES,default='Like', max_length=10)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.post)
```

Comment: Can you share your models? "The objective is to get the no of likes in descending order" - the no of likes grouped by what?

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: You want a `Post` queryset that is annotated with and sorted by the number of related `Like` objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will give you the queryset containing dictionaries in it.

```
query = Like.objects.filter(value='Like').values()
```